# Count number of files of each sub-directory

Tags: command-line

I have hundreds of directories in `videos` directory. I want to count number of files of each sub-directory. For each sub-directory, I can use `ls -1 | wc -l` to count number of files in it. But I can not manually repeat the command hundred times. Could you please tell me other commands to count number of files of each sub-directory? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple use of `find` and `wc`

```
MusicDir='/home/MyUser/Music'
find "$MusicDir" -type d | while read D; do echo -e "$(find "$D" -type f | wc -l)\t$D"; done

## Example OUTPUT
206 ./AC-DC
9   ./AC-DC/1975 - High Voltage (Australia Only)
11  ./AC-DC/1975 - T.N.T (Australia Only)
10  ./AC-DC/1976 - Dirty Deeds Done Dirt Cheap (International version)
10  ./AC-DC/1976 - High Voltage (International version)
10  ./AC-DC/1977 - Let There Be Rock
11  ./AC-DC/1978 - Powerage
11  ./AC-DC/1979 - Highway To Hell
13  ./AC-DC/1980 - Back In Black
11  ./AC-DC/1981 - For Those About To Rock (We Salute You)
11  ./AC-DC/1983 - Flick Of The Switch
6   ./AC-DC/1984 - 74 Jailbreak
11  ./AC-DC/1985 - Fly On The Wall
11  ./AC-DC/1988 - Blow Up Your Video
14  ./AC-DC/1990 - The Razor's Edge
13  ./AC-DC/1995 - Ballbreaker
13  ./AC-DC/2000 - Stiff Upper Lip
16  ./AC-DC/2008 - Black Ice
12  ./AC-DC/2014 - Rock or Bust
```

The output could also be sorted (second column,  alpha)

```
MusicDir='/home/MyUser/Music'
find "$MusicDir" -type d | while read D; do echo -e "$(find "$D" -type f | wc -l)\t$D"; done | sort -k2
```

Comment: I’d consider adding `-maxdepth 1` to disable recursion into subdirectories and `-mindepth 1` to disable counting `.` but in a well-defined special case, the original command might work well.